# Fine tuning Conditional GANs for low data scenarios

Tags: deep-learning, gan, generative-models

I was wondering what the process was for fine tuning a conditional GAN. For example, say I wanted to generate pictures of an object X given a certain condition such as a sentence describing it, which is proposed and implemented in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.05396.pdf). The condition would be embedded into a vector, call it ***c***. However, say that annotated images of object X are rare, but un-annotated images of object X (images that are of object X but do not have a sentence describing it) are plentiful.


How would I go about training a conditional GAN on this data? Would I initially train the GAN with the un-annotated images of object X while setting the condition vector ***c*** to a zero vector so that the model learns to generate images of object X without conditions, then fine tune the model on the annotated images of object X, where ***c*** is the condition, so that the model learns the relationship between the given condition and the images it should generate at the end? Or is there some other way to go about this?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this particular problem?